# QNetworkAccessManager for google cloud messaging

Tags: c++, qt, google-cloud-messaging, qnetworkaccessmanager

```
       final String[][]  MESSAGE_HEADERS = {
           {"Content-Type", "application/json"},
           { "Authorization", "key=" + AUTH_KEY}
       };
```

How make it on Qt?
I tried this:

```
QNetworkRequest request(url);
request.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentTypeHeader, "application/json");
request.setHeader("Authorization", "key=AIzaSyBzFcuWKSNn0cJIDQ1EA9jbCom7d8U");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`setHeader()`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5-snapshot/qnetworkrequest.html#setHeader) does only work with a limited list of [`KnownHeaders`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5-snapshot/qnetworkrequest.html#KnownHeaders-enum) as used in your first line. For the second header line with a custom header key, you need to use [`setRawHeader()`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5-snapshot/qnetworkrequest.html#setRawHeader)

```
QNetworkRequest request(url);
request.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentTypeHeader, "application/json");
request.setRawHeader(QByteArray("Authorization"), QByteArray("key=AIzaSyBzFcuWKSNn04O3hcJIDQ1EA9jbCom7d8U"));
```